# What does this syntax do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Shortly I am not aware of what the following syntax do?

```
const { statusCode } = res;
```

or this

```
const { method, url } = request;
```

Is this a definition of the variable `statusCode` or something else?

Comment: `const { statusCode } = res;` === `const statusCode = res.statusCode`

Comment: It is called a destructuring assignment, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Syntax questions are _easily_ answerable with a [reference from the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Comment: @Xufox I wasn't able to find such expression in the reference you give.

Comment: It’s `{a, b} = {a:1, b:2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `const { statusCode } = res` means `const statusCode = res.statusCode` !

Same for the other example:

`const { method, url } = request` into

```
const method = request.method;
const url = request.url;
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: replace the `,` with a `;` in `method, const` or remove `const` and you'll have it right :p